# How do I add functions to my custom types?

Tags: typescript

I am using io-ts to check types.

```
export type UserType = t.TypeOf<typeof User>
```

how do i add a function to that type so i can do stuff like

```
const user : UserType {...}
user.getName()
```

Comment: `export type UserType = t.TypeOf<typeof User> & { getName: () => string };` ?

Comment: @zerkms where do i put function logic?

Comment: Wherever the `const user` value comes from.

Comment: i use the io-ts encode function and then cast it as the Type...

Comment: Good, so wherever you produce the value - add it at that place.